# How can I assign values from text to variables?

Tags: shell-script, awk, cut

I have this text:

```
node1: connect command: ssh user@123.23.23.23 password: qcipunbnctza
node2: connect command: ssh user@123.23.23.44 password: ejrpnnwsczpa
node3: connect command: ssh user@123.23.23.66 password: pkrpxmyxnxuu
```

I need to save ip addresses and passwords to variables then pass it to script.
How can I do in in efficent way?
My script is:

```
#/bin/bash
declare -a IPS=($1 $2 $3)
CONFIG_FILE=inventory/sks-cluster/hosts.yaml python3 contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py ${IPS[@]}
echo $4 > host1.txt
echo $5 > host2.txt
echo $6 > host3.txt
ssh-keyscan $1
ssh-keyscan $2
ssh-keyscan $3
sshpass -f host1.txt ssh-copy-id user@$1
sshpass -f host2.txt ssh-copy-id user@$2
sshpass -f host3.txt ssh-copy-id user@$3
```

Comment: Unless the `python3 contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py` has to run on all IP's at the same time it would be neater and simpler to loop over the lines instead.

Comment: Even if simultaneous execution was required, it would still be simpler and neater to use a loop.  just run each python3 instance in the background with `&`, possibly redirecting stdout & stderr to either /dev/null or to a separate log file for each host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export SSHPASS
awk -F'[@ ]' '{print $5, $6, $8}' hostlist.txt |
  while read -r username host SSHPASS ; do
    echo ssh-keyscan "$host"
    echo sshpass -e ssh-copy-id "$username@$host"
done
```

This uses an awk one-liner to extract the username, the hostname/IP address, and the password of each line from a file called `hostlist.txt`, with the output being piped into a `while` loop.

The `while` loop processes the output from `awk` and uses it with `ssh-keyscan` and `sshpass` (using the `-e` option instead of `-f`, so that it uses the environment variable `$SSHPASS` instead of a file) for each input line.

`SSHPASS` is exported to ensure that it is available in the environment when `sshpass` is run.

NOTE: I've used `echo` before `ssh-keyscan` and `sshpass` to make this a dry-run (and because testing it is faster if my system doesn't have to waste time trying to connect to those IP addresses with ssh-keyscan and ssh-pass+ssh-copy-id).  Remove the `echo`  from both lines when you're sure it's going to work as intended.

Comment: Til: `-F'[@ ]'` , how very useful

Comment: @Nifle  `@|[[:blank:]]+` works too. probably works better in most cases because it allows one or more spaces or tabs as the field separator (same as the awk default) rather than just a single space.  awk allows any regex (ERE syntax) for `FS`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very naive way to do it.

If your script is called `yourscript.sh` and the data is in a file called `nodes.txt`

```
yourscript.sh  $(cat nodes.txt |  tr '@' ' ' | cut -f6 -d' '; cut -f7 -d' ' nodes.txt)
```

Comment: can you explain how works cut in this case? First we truncate '@', then pass all colums to cut. And how it works after that?

Comment: @VladF 'tr' replaces the `@`with a space, cut can then select colum 6 using space as a field separator, this prinys the ip-numbers `;` starts a new command where we extract the password using `cut`  The `$( ..... )` runs the code inside it and returns whatever is printed to stdout on one line.